# Where is a good location to unlock the faster health regeneration perk?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

Unlocking the faster health regeneration perk required you to hit 200 health. Since overcharged health declines until it hits 100 this strikes me as the kind of perk that can only be unlocked in very specific areas, and that you need to know ahead of time that the area contains enough health (since I'm assuming you'll need to dash around the area without taking damage picking up health packs). The perk seems really handy, so I don't want to miss my chance to unlock it.

Where is a good location to hit 200 health, and unlock the health regeneration perk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really good location for unlocking the perk is in the first level, in the room with the giant nazi picture. I've included a screenshot of the room below, but the the picture isn't visible (since it's also a secret door which I already opened):

[image]

The top floor alone contains enough to bring you from 100 -> 200 health, and the bottom floor contains 60 health worth of packs, so unless you go strolling into this area with less than 40 health you're guaranteed to gather enough health to unlock the perk.

The trick to unlocking the perk here is to just clear out all the enemies (ideally using stealth), and then dash through the top floor picking up all the health items you can. You can open up the painting by interacting with the Knight to the left of it (the one with the askew sword), which will take you up behind one of the commanders, allowing you to easily get a stealth kill on him.

Answer (score 3):

For me I did it right before destroying the first stomper in chapter 1,

1. After you enter the bunker clear the way from enemies and reach 3rd floor (O3)
2. Kill all enemies on 3rd floor, given that you still have full health (100), there are two small +20 health packages and another +40 health package on the floor, consume them.
3. Quickly run up to 4th floor (O4) to the end of small railway where there's an elevator with two blue crates, on top of them is a big +80 health package, consume that and you will overcharge your health with over 200

This is very easy and fast to do.